# 500 Internal Server Error when trying to use ErrorDocument to handle request

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?(.*)$ ./$1.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

However, when I go to `localhost/example.php`, it returns a 500 Internal Server Error.

Any help please? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The full error message that comes up is:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /example.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: Have you tried the answer I posted below?

Comment: I voted to close this question because a 500 error is a very generic "something went wrong" error.  It could be a misconfiguration, a permissions problem, or a coding error.  More information about the specific cause of your error is available in your server's error log.  There is no way to accurately answer this question without seeing the logs.  Any answers here will be guesses and there are hundreds if not thousands of possible answers.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I think the question is fine because it received an answer that worked for OP. If you are a mod rewrite expert please check the post below and edit the title to make it more specific, this would be more helpful for the community than closing the question.

Comment: The problem is this answer is not likely to serve others with similar issues very well. It is also likely to accumulate a huge number of other answers over time as people find other 500 errors that they managed to solve in some other way.  Such an additional answer was just recently added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're most likely getting 500 due to looping error.

Exclude `404.php` from last rule as:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!404\.php)$ - [L,NC,R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ ./$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Yes, this works :) However, when I visit a page that exists e.g. `index.php`, it loads `index.php` instead of `404.php`. Any idea of how this could be done?

Comment: If a page exists then than that page's .php will be loaded not 404.php. 404.php will be shown only when a page.php doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh. Basically, my intentions are to remove and to prevent the use of `.php` in the URL (if the user tries to use/add `.php` in the URL, it would result in a 404 error). Could you suggest a method of doing this through htaccess?

Comment: Isn't your rule already doing that? However instead of showing 404 for .php you should show 403 (Forbidden) error which is more common.

Comment: Yes, but if the user tries to access a page that exists e.g. `user.php`, it will load `users.php` instead of loading `404.php`. It should only load `users.php` if the request is `/users`.

Comment: It is awfully late here so this is my last comment. That's not the behavior I am noticing. In you present rules: `/user.php` will cause 404 and if `/users.php` exists then `/users` shows correct page. Make sure you don't have any other rule/.htaccess conflicting.

Comment: Sorry - I missed out the `s` on the end of `user.php`. I mean that even if the user access e.g. `index.php` and it exists, it would still give a 404 error unless they access it by `/index`.

Comment: I think it's due to my poor wording of my comment (sorry). If the user tries to access any file with `.php` (even if it exists e.g. `/index.php`), I want it to redirect to a 404. The user must **not** have the `.php` ending otherwise I want it to end in a 404 (it must be `/index`). The current situation is that they **can** use the `.php` extention, and I want that to not be possible.

Comment: But before my recent edit it is exactly what was happening I.e. any. .php file was generating 404 in my testing. You just need to my suggested rule before your other rule that adds .php silently.

Comment: OK see my answer again. I have now provided you full htaccess.

Comment: When I tested it, it loaded up the page that is being requested instead of 404.php. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: It could be due to MultiViews option. If you notice my answer I have switched it off.

Comment: I have literally copy and pasted your htaccess into mine

Comment: I am not sure then because it has been working fine for me all the time in a blank htaccess.

Comment: You're welcome and sorry I couldn't actively support your problem today as I was traveling and responding via my mobile.

Answer (score 3):

is 404.php actually set in the root of your filesystem?

I'm guessing not.

Try something like ../404.php

BTW: Did you look in your apache log files?

Comment: This is most likely the problem but I don't think `../404.php` is appropriate

Comment: @Phil : please share why

Comment: The 404.php **is** located in the root :(

Comment: @user3130907 The root of your filesystem (hard drive) or the root of your website? /404.php indicates the root of your filesystem (hard drive)

Comment: It is stored in the `www` folder

Comment: @user3130907 you can use relative paths as I suggested (EG `../404.php`) or you can use absolute paths: `/path/to/my/www/folder/404.php` (EG `/var/html/www/404.php` or whatever it is in your case)

Comment: When I try to use a relative path (`../404.php`), all that comes up on the page is `../404.php`

Answer (score 1):

You just Add this code in your .htaccess file

```
# BEGING WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: You can improve this answer by explaining what this does or how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to hide .php extension in your pages, try to remove that extension from the .htaccess file by doing the following:

Change: ErrorDocument 404 /404.php to ErrorDocument 404 /404

Hope this helps.

JJ

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this issue. But my error is disk of server is full 100%. You should check your server disk, as a consider solution.