# 500 Internal Server Error due to htacess config

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I tried to configure my htacess for multiples reasons :

First I have my views pages in this path : **mywebsite.fr/views/contact-us.php** (for example). I want access to files in the **/views** without being in the url and without extention format; like this : **mywebsite.fr/contact-us**

I written this lines and it working very nicely :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Retirer les extensions des pages et les rendre accessibles en lecture
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

# WWW => domaine
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.mywebsite.fr
RewriteRule (.*) http://mywebsite.fr$1 [L,R=301]

# Suppression d'un sous répertoire
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /views/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But when I try to open an unexisting page, I have a redirection in page error 500 Internal Server Error instead my 404 page custom...

Theses error pages are in this path : **mywebsite/views/errors/404.php**

And I written this lines in my htaccess file :

```
ErrorDocument  404  /views/errors/404
```

Maybe someone can say me why the page 404 are not deployed ? Thank's

Comment: `Maybe someone can say me why the page 404 are not deployed?` Yes, your apache error log will.

Comment: Ahm, you don't have to put the extension in your /views/errors/404, like */views/errors/404.php*?

Comment: Do you have another htaccess file?

Comment: @DimasPante I tried with extension but anything changed. I also read this post but I dont know how, and where I have to read the exeption format in my RewriteRule (If I have to ...). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752140/500-internal-server-error-when-trying-to-use-errordocument-to-handle-request#_=_

Comment: @JonLin Yes I have in the directory /view but he is empty. He shouldn't ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have an htaccess file in `/views/` with rewrite rules in it, this rule will cause a rewrite loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /views/$1 [QSA,L]
```

If you go to `/not-exist` the two conditions will pass, and the URI gets rewritten to `/views/not-exist`, and the rewrite engine loops. Since that doesn't exist either, your conditions will pass again, and the URI gets rewritten to `/views/views/not-exist`, etc.

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/views/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/views/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/views/$1.php -f 
RewriteRule (.*) /views/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That working ! Thank's u for the tip about the rewrite loop... Now the problem is... When I go in mywebsite.fr I have a redirection to 403 (custom page).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found finally the solution :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # Retirer les extensions des pages et les rendres accessibles en lecture
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

    # Suppression d'un sous répertoire
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/views/$1.php -f 
    RewriteRule (.*) /views/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

And for my custom error pages :

```
ErrorDocument  401  /views/errors/401.php
ErrorDocument  403  /views/errors/403.php
ErrorDocument  404  /views/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument  500  /views/errors/500.php
```

Now all working correcly.

Comment: It would be most helpful to others to edit the answer to point out which parts caused the error and how you fixed it without having to do a line by line comparison.  After all, the point of SO is _"to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming"_.  Thanks.